# Access violation while reading csv file in C

Tags: c, csv, access-violation

I am writing into a csv file in my code and then reading it from a different function.
Here is the code for writing the file

```
FILE* fpt1;
errno_t err3;
err3 = fopen_s(&fpt1, "Ay.csv", "w+");
if (err3 == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fpt1, "%d\n",Ay[i]);
    }
}

fclose(fpt1);
```

Here is for reading the file:

```
int *Ay;
Ay = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
FILE* file;
errno_t err;
char line[20000], * number = NULL, * number1 = NULL;
w = 0;
err = fopen_s(&file, "Ay.csv", "r");
if (err == 0)
{
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        number = strtok(line, ",", &number1);
        while (number != NULL)
        {
            Ay[w] = atoi(number);
            number = strtok(NULL, ",", &number1);
            w++;
        }
    }
}
fclose(file);
```

I have to run this in a loop. First writing into the file and then reading it from a different function. I'm not sure where I went wrong here. But it shows " 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location error" while reading pointing to the Ay[w] = atoi(number) line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When reading what is `n`? Please edit your question and post the definition and initialization and where it is done relative to the `malloc`

Comment: Did you copy this code into the question by hand? Is `strtok` supposed to be `strtok_r`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: If `n` isn't specified properly or is too small, an alternate way is ... `int *Ay = NULL;` and in the loop just above `Ay[w] = atoi(number);` insert: `Ay = realloc(Ay,sizeof(*Ay) * (w + 1));` You can add error checking for the `realloc` with: `if (Ay == NULL) { perror("realloc"); exit(1); }`